# Пожирание оперативной памяти C#

Tags: c#, winforms, память

ПО написанное в winforms для транспорта, позволяет печатать сопроводительные документы. На `datagridview` сделано меню правой кнопки мыши, в зависимости от выбранного рейса генерится отчет в новом окне в reportViewer, который собственно и является печатной формой документа. стал замечать что при каждом вызове отчета процесс ПО пожирает оперативную память на 2-3мб больше. Я новичок в c# что делать не знаю, прошу помочь. Сейчас сделал так:

Вызов документа

```
private void callWaybill()
{
    Waybill f6 = new Waybill();
    f6.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

В основной форме сделал такое

```
public void Dispose()
{
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect(1, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
}
```

При закрытие формы с документом, делаю так:

```
private void Waybill_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    main m = this.Owner as main;
    m.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Не, вы делаете неправильно. Ручная сборка мусора не может помочь в принципе. Если у вас утечка памяти, возьмите любой memory profiler и посмотрите, где именно она утекает.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ, вы не посоветуете какой нибудь memory profiler для нубасов?

Comment: Возьмите [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), он по-моему хороший. Он стоит денег, но две недели бесплатный период, так что вы вполне успеете решить проблему. (Ну и если проблема возникает часто, заставьте начальство купить, если вам он подойдёт.)

Comment: @VladD, поставил, но пока не могу понять чем он может помочь, я в нем вижу просто повышение использование памяти, что в принципе и так видел в task manager. Я вот думаю может быть проблема в том что я при каждом клике генерю новую форму, а когда перестаю с ней работать(когда пользователь ее закрывает кликом по крестику) она остается где то в фоне и создается новая, может их как то надо разрушать?

Comment: Ну, в нём можно сделать снимок памяти до какого-нибудь действия и после него, и посмотреть, какие объекты остались в памяти. И кто эти объекты в памяти держит.

Comment: @VladD после анализа вижу что память увеличивается в категории "Unmanaged", и эта категория не имеет расшифровки, я так понял это куча?

Comment: Unmanaged — это не куча, это нативная память. Вы не используете нативных библиотек случайно? Ну и всё же посмотрите список добавившихся объектов, **он важен**.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47378/discussion-between-winteriscoming-and-vladd).